# accuracy of libsvm is not right

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I am doing libsvm as shown there:

```
numLabels = max(trainlabels);
model = cell(numLabels,1);
for k=1:numLabels
    model{k} = svmtrain(double(trainlabels==k), train_data, '-t 0 -b 1');
end

numTest = size(test_data,1);
prob = zeros(numTest,numLabels);
for k=1:numLabels
    [predicted_label, accuracy, prob_estimates] = svmpredict(double(testlabels==k), test_data, model{k}, '-b 1');
    fprintf('sum(predicted_label==1) = %i \n', sum(predicted_label==1));
    fprintf('sum(testlabels==k) = %i \n', sum(testlabels==k));
    cc = model{k}.Label==1;
    prob(:,k) = prob_estimates(:,cc);    %# probability of class==k
end

%# predict the class with the highest probability
[~,pred] = max(prob,[],2);
acc = sum(pred == testlabels) ./ numel(testlabels);    %# accuracy
fprintf('Final accuracy = %f %\n', acc*100);
```

I got accuracy always above 80% (~83%), and sum of predicted label of each iteration is almost zero, and final accuracy is 11%. As shown below:

```
Accuracy = 65% (39/60) (classification)
sum(predicted_label==1) = 17 
Accuracy = 83.3333% (50/60) (classification)
sum(predicted_label==1) = 0 
Accuracy = 83.3333% (50/60) (classification)
sum(predicted_label==1) = 0 
Accuracy = 63.3333% (38/60) (classification)
sum(predicted_label==1) = 16 
Accuracy = 83.3333% (50/60) (classification)
sum(predicted_label==1) = 0 
Accuracy = 83.3333% (50/60) (classification)
sum(predicted_label==1) = 0 
Final accuracy = 11.666667 >>
```

How this happens ? What I am doing wrong here ???

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your code is fine.
The reason you get the low accuracy is that svm does not work well on this dataset.

As you can see, in several model, your svm just predicts everything to be negative.
This means it is not that confident for predicting the positive label.
Therefore, when you combine all the probability in the end, the accuracy is bad.

I suggest you to try another kernel with svm to see the result.

Comment: Bur do you have any idea why the accuracy for each model is not synchronized with the predicted labels for each mode ?

Comment: I think it's synchronized. For example, in the second model, your accuracy is 83, that is because svm predict everything to be negative. I believe that there are 10 positive labels and 50 negative for this model.

Comment: but predicted_label presents how many positive labels you have, it returns zero, because all the elements are negative, hence the classification should be 0/60. I am asking about the synchronized between the accuracy (83%) and sum of predicted label (0).

Comment: Suppose you have 60 items, 50 are negative and 10 are positive. If your svm predicts all of them to be negative, then the accuracy will be 50/60, and sum of ur predicted labels are 0